# Failing to pass URL to a view from a controller in ionic

Tags: angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, youtube

I am attempting to pass a Youtube video URL to an iframe view that plays the Youtube video. However, when I open the view, it displays a white page and nothing else.

Controller

```
.controller('youtubeCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicSideMenuDelegate){

  // Pop-up Navigation Menu
  $scope.openMenu = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  }

  $scope.video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/LFTEUBHpFq0";
})
```

View

```
<ion-view title="Youtube">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-content>
    <div class="video-container">
        <iframe ng-src={{video_url}} frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I want to pass'video_url' to open the iframe and play. But that is not happening. What exactly am I doing wrong or not doing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work when you are running it from a web browser? If you haven't allowed youtube.com in your ionic app, it is possible that the app will not be allowed to access content from that url. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#network-request-whitelist

Comment: It works in the web browser.

Comment: It will be useful if you could post the logs in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you need to inject the `$sce` service in the controller and `trustAsResourceUrl` the url there.

In your controller.

```
.controller('youtubeCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $sce){

  // Pop-up Navigation Menu
  $scope.openMenu = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  }
  var videoSource = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/LFTEUBHpFq0"; 
  $scope.video_url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(videoSource)

})
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/77kzu28b/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks big time. It worked like a charm. I'm so happy. Thanks again.

Comment: @BlakeTucker I'm glad it helped, But does this answer haven't met your question requirement?

Comment: In the page-view, I wasn't able to view and play the youtube video. I tried adding $https to my controller, as well as doing alot of other things. All in vain. but when I added $sce to my controller, I was able to view and play the youtube video in the page view.

ionic 1.7.8,
node v0.12.1,
cordova v5.4.0

Comment: Great. but you should mark this answer correct right. :)